# Jquery Ajax returns 400 BAD request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to send data to my local DB server but I keep getting 400 Bad request error when I try to send it.

```
var studentEmail = "ali@gmail.com";
            var dataString = '&questionNumber='+ temp + '&answer='+ value + '&email='+ studentEmail;


            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            url: "js/dbcon.php",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
```

and this is the php file

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root"); // Establishing Connection with Server..
$db = mysql_select_db("db", $connection); // Selecting Database
//Fetching Values from URL
$questionNumber=$_POST['questionNumber'];
$answer=$_POST['answer'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
//Insert query
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (questionNumber,studentAnswer,studentEmail) VALUES ($questionNumber,$answer,$email)");
echo "succesfully posted";
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```

can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ps if I change POST to GET it works but doesnt insert the data to my DB

Comment: You're sure that dbcon.php is in the js folder? Seems rather strange...

Comment: You must escape the string `@` is not valid inside a URL.

Comment: This is not good: You are not sending key-value pairs, so you will not get any data from `$_POST` on the server, you are not sending back json so your ajax call will never finish successfully, you have an sql injection problem and you use a deprecated mysql api.

Comment: I made sure the php file is in the js folder

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` method is used to turn a javascript **`object`** into json string.

So `dataString` variable must be a javascript `object`:

```
var data ={questionNumber:temp ,answer: value ,email:studentEmail};
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json',
    url: "js/dbcon.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did the change you said and now I get 404 error instead, I also made sure the php file is in the js folder

Comment: I think that it can't found your file, but my change should work if it found the file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, what you said is incorrect, because you've used `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and that represents the type of data you're sending.

Answer (score 1):

if you change the post to get you have to replace $_POST with $_GET into your php file.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to pass data that will work correctly for both POST and GET requests

```
var studentEmail = "ali@gmail.com";
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        url: "js/dbcon.php",
        data: {questionNumber:temp, answer:value, email: studentEmail},
        processData: false,

});
```

Now jQuery does all the hard work and converts the object full of data to whatever format is required for a POST or GET request

Answer (score 1):

You can send the `ajax` request this way:

```
var studentEmail = "ali@gmail.com";
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            url: "js/dbcon.php",
            data: ({'questionNumber':temp,'answer':value, 'email':studentEmail }),
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
```

Also the PHP file needs to return a `json` string as well.

```
echo "succesfully posted";
```

is no valid `json` answer.

Return something like this:

```
$arr = array('success' => true, 'answer' => "succesfully posted");

echo json_encode($arr);
```

See also here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

You should validate the input data, before inserting into the database.